# Possible to replace image with another image in a PDF with powershell?

Tags: powershell, pdf

We have hundreds of PDF files that have an old logo in them. I need to replace them all and was hoping there was a way to automate it with powershell.

I'm not sure where to begin or if anyone had suggestions on performing the task (or a better solution than powershell).

Comment: You can leverage something like [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7) or the older (and free) [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/). Provide a sample pdf if you want some example code.

Comment: Here is a link to my google drive with a sample PDF. The header and footer are images on each page that need to be replaced. I've installed the packages for iTextSharp but having some difficulty finding some good examples. Thank you for your time

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pgbolowvD1geJYB1_QyGdU7c5w2QNQfj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry missed your update, will check it out. Re your issue #1 I'd get legal advice if you're unsure, but I don't think updating the logo will invalidate the docs. IANAL tho. Issue #2, will keep in mind when I check the sample. Haven't used itextsharp in a couple years!

Comment: I should also state that these documents are currently used, but have an old logo from before a conversion...just found them and would rather do this via scripting/software than manually editing hundreds/thousands of documents. 

The locations of the images never change across all the documents.